# How to show drop down select in button in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

Here I am listing hour and minute in two different buttons. I can able to drop down hour and minute, but not showed selected value in button.

```
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
          <button id="startHour" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">hour</button>

            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="startHour">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">1</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">3</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">4</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">5</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">6</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">7</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">8</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">9</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">10</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">11</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">12</a>
            </div>
            <span style="color:white; background-color:#5A6268">:</span>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
          <button id="startMinute" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" 
data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">min</button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="startMinute">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">00</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">05</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">10</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">15</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">20</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">25</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">30</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">35</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">40</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">45</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">50</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">55</a>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">am</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">zone</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Set</button>

      </div>
```

And javascript I used

```
  $(".dropdown-menu a").click(function(){
    var selText = $(this).text();
  $(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.btn-secondary').html(selText);
   });
```

By using above js code I can able to display selected value in button, but it changes value to all drop down list.
Here is the screenshots which i am getting [image: screenshot]

Comment: You forgot a closing tag `</div>` for the first `btn-group`, so both `.btn-secondary`s are being selected. Typo question

Comment: @CertainPerformance  i have edited my question . can you check it out

Comment: You still aren't closing the `div`, so of course it's not working. Look at the tidied code: https://jsfiddle.net/j7yruoto/

Comment: @CertainPerformance it changing value for all

Comment: Yes, and that is because the first `div` isn't closed - like I said, **look at the tidied code**. Close your divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it changing value for all – PvDev

Is your problem the dropdown or setting the values to the right section? Maybe this will help. Not sure if i understood your question:
Jquery

```
$(".dropdown-menu a").click(function(){
    var selText = $(this).text();
    var currentBtn = $(this).closest(".btn-group").children("button");
    var currentUnit = currentBtn.data("unit");
    currentBtn.html(selText);
        console.log(currentUnit);
    $("."+ currentUnit).text(selText);
   });
```

Html

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
  <button id="startHour" type="button" data-unit="hours"  class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">hour</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="startHour">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">1</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">3</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">4</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">5</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">6</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">7</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">8</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">9</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">10</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">11</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">12</a>
  </div>
  <span style="color:white; background-color:#5A6268">:</span>
</div>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
  <button id="startMinute" type="button" data-unit="minutes" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">min</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="startMinute">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">00</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">05</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">10</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">15</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">20</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">25</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">30</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">35</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">40</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">45</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">50</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">55</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="output">
  <button type="button" class="hours btn btn-secondary">am</button>
  <button type="button" class="minutes btn btn-secondary">zone</button>
  <button type="button" class="seconds btn btn-primary">Set</button>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Rakowu/t982sLuj/1/

I gave your group elements a data attr to figure out what kind of unit your clicking on. Than i select the output element with the callback.
Hope it will help
(If there are ideas on how reduce my code i'll glad to here about it :D)

Comment: @while giving div, it changing design. design should be like above screnshot

Comment: But is it what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close the divs

```js
$(".dropdown-menu a").click(function() {
  var selText = $(this).text();
  $(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.btn-secondary').html(selText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
  <button id="startHour" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">hour</button>

  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="startHour">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">1</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">2</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">3</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">4</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">5</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">6</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">7</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">8</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">9</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">10</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">11</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">12</a>
  </div>
    </div>
  <span style="color:white; background-color:#5A6268">:</span>
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
    <button id="startMinute" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">min</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="startMinute">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">00</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">05</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">10</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">15</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">20</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">25</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">30</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">35</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">40</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">45</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">50</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">55</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Typo questions such as this one are off-topic and should not be answered.

Comment: it changing values for all